# Как данные за день продублировать на следующий день sql-запросом? (MsSql)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеются данные в бд
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно скопировать эти данные но уже с датой следующего дня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура используемой таблицы:

```
CREATE table info(
    id int auto_increment  primary key,
    date DATETIME not null,
    _number INTEGER
);
```

Ее заполнение:

```
INSERT INTO info 
(date, _number) 
values 
    ('1000-05-03 00:00:00', 1), 
    ('2001-01-02 00:00:00', 3);
```

---

Вот, как можно прибавить `n`-ое кол-во дней к дате:

```
DATE_ADD('2008-01-02 13:38:50.02', INTERVAL n DAY)
```

Не составит труда теперь составить запрос:

```
INSERT INTO info 
(date, _number) 
SELECT 
    DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) as date,
    _number
FROM 
    info;
```

Если вызовем команду `SELECT * FROM info`, то получим вывод:

> ## id, date, _number
>
> '1', '1000-05-03 00:00:00', '1'
>   '2', '2001-01-02 00:00:00', '3'
>   '3', '1000-05-04 00:00:00', '1'
>   '4', '2001-01-03 00:00:00', '3'

Comment: Добавь ещё WHERE по дате (хотя бы комментированный, но чтоб было) - а то уже завтра получится перебор.